# finding the Flink CEP detection latency for each tuple

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep

I have a simple pattern as shown below

```
 Pattern<Event,?> pattern = Pattern.<Event>begin("s1")
                    .where(new SimpleCondition<Event>() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean filter(Event event) throws Exception {

                            Long time = System.nanoTime();
                            // here we are setting the time when this event is detected
                            event.setEdtl(time);

                            return event.getSensor_id() == 1 && event.getValue() > 150;
                        }
                    }).followedBy("s2")
                    .where(new SimpleCondition<Event>() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean filter(Event event) throws Exception {
                            Long time = System.nanoTime();

                            // here we are setting the time when this event is detected
                            event.setEdtl(time);

                            return event.getSensor_id() == 2 && event.getValue() > 15;
                        }
                    }).followedBy("s3")
                    .where(new SimpleCondition<Event>() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean filter(Event event) throws Exception {

                            Long time = System.nanoTime();
                            // here we are setting the time when this event is detected
                            event.setEdtl(time);
                            return event.getSensor_id() == 3 && event.getValue() > 35;
                        }
                    })
                    .within(Time.milliseconds(WindowLength_join__ms));
```

in order to find the latency of CEP detection time, added the time each event is selected in the pattern as shown above. Each event class has a parameter `Edtl` (event detection time local), which is initially set to 0 and then later on it is set to  `System.nanoTime();`

I am getting following error while execution, but thing is that the error comes after program runs for some time

```
    Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Job execution failed.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anonfun$handleMessage$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$7.apply$mcV$sp(JobManager.scala:933)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anonfun$handleMessage$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$7.apply(JobManager.scala:876)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anonfun$handleMessage$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$7.apply(JobManager.scala:876)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:40)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:397)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception occurred while processing valve output watermark: 
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamInputProcessor$ForwardingValveOutputHandler.handleWatermark(StreamInputProcessor.java:289)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.streamstatus.StatusWatermarkValve.findAndOutputNewMinWatermarkAcrossAlignedChannels(StatusWatermarkValve.java:173)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.streamstatus.StatusWatermarkValve.inputWatermark(StatusWatermarkValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamInputProcessor.processInput(StreamInputProcessor.java:188)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OneInputStreamTask.run(OneInputStreamTask.java:69)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:263)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:702)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.ExceptionInChainedOperatorException: Could not forward element to next operator
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.pushToOperator(OperatorChain.java:530)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.collect(OperatorChain.java:503)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.collect(OperatorChain.java:483)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator$CountingOutput.collect(AbstractStreamOperator.java:891)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator$CountingOutput.collect(AbstractStreamOperator.java:869)
    at org.apache.flink.cep.operator.KeyedCEPPatternOperator.emitMatchedSequences(KeyedCEPPatternOperator.java:77)
    at org.apache.flink.cep.operator.KeyedCEPPatternOperator.processEvent(KeyedCEPPatternOperator.java:58)
    at org.apache.flink.cep.operator.AbstractKeyedCEPPatternOperator.onEventTime(AbstractKeyedCEPPatternOperator.java:236)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.HeapInternalTimerService.advanceWatermark(HeapInternalTimerService.java:275)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.InternalTimeServiceManager.advanceWatermark(InternalTimeServiceManager.java:107)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator.processWatermark(AbstractStreamOperator.java:946)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamInputProcessor$ForwardingValveOutputHandler.handleWatermark(StreamInputProcessor.java:286)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.ExceptionInChainedOperatorException: Could not forward element to next operator
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.pushToOperator(OperatorChain.java:530)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.collect(OperatorChain.java:503)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.collect(OperatorChain.java:483)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$BroadcastingOutputCollector.collect(OperatorChain.java:575)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$BroadcastingOutputCollector.collect(OperatorChain.java:536)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator$CountingOutput.collect(AbstractStreamOperator.java:891)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator$CountingOutput.collect(AbstractStreamOperator.java:869)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamMap.processElement(StreamMap.java:41)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.pushToOperator(OperatorChain.java:528)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to send message 'patient_id=1, egtl_raw=null, edtg=null
' to socket server at localhost:6020. Connection re-tries are not enabled.
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.SocketClientSink.invoke(SocketClientSink.java:154)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSink.processElement(StreamSink.java:41)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.pushToOperator(OperatorChain.java:528)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:111)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:143)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.SocketClientSink.invoke(SocketClientSink.java:146)
```

I think I pattern this is because I am doing both read and write operation inside the pattern. If this is so, then how should I find the average complex event latency in Flink CEP.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I have figured out the solution, which might not be the best one, but it works. Finding the [CE] complex event latency in above figure we need to find the time when CE was detected and the minimum raw event time and then find the difference between these times. The reason I am using minimum here is that let's say 3 streams `a, b & c` are included in the complex event, so whosoever has to wait for the most, we will consider its time. In my opinion, it can be selected from the pattern.

**Task 1:** assigning the timestamp to the first pattern, this is done as shown below

```
if(perform_cep ){

        // performing some cep on merged stream


        Pattern<Event,?> pattern = Pattern.<Event>begin("s1")
                .where(new SimpleCondition<Event>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean filter(Event event) throws Exception {

                        // here we are setting the time when this event is detected

                        if(event.getSensor_id() == 1 && event.getValue() > 150){
                            Long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
                            event.setEdtl(time);
                            return true;

                        }
                        else return false;

                    }
                }).followedBy("s2")
                .where(new SimpleCondition<Event>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean filter(Event event) throws Exception {

                        return  event.getSensor_id() == 2 && event.getValue() > 15 ;

                    }
                }).followedBy("s3")
                .where(new SimpleCondition<Event>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean filter(Event event) throws Exception {

                       return  event.getSensor_id() == 3 && event.getValue() > 35;

                    }
                })
                .within(Time.milliseconds(WindowLength_join__ms));
```

**Task 2:** Assigning timestamp to the complex event stream and finding latency. This is done as follows

```
 PatternStream<Event> patternStream = CEP.pattern(mergedStream,pattern);



            DataStream<String> cep_stream = patternStream.select(new PatternSelectFunction<Event, String>() {


  @Override
            public String select(Map<String, List<Event>> map) throws Exception {

                Event s1 = map.get("s1").get(0);

                Integer patient_id = s1.getPatient_id();
                Integer val1 = s1.getValue();
                Long time_s1 = s1.getEdtl();



                Event s2 = map.get("s2").get(0);
                Integer val2 = s2.getValue();


                Event s3 = map.get("s3").get(0);
                Integer val3 = s3.getValue();



                System.out.println("value 1  = " + val1);
                System.out.println("value 2  = " + val2);
                System.out.println("value 3  = " + val3);



                Long current_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
                Long cep_latency = current_time - time_s1 ;
                System.out.println("cep_latency = " + cep_latency + "ms" );


                String event_data =  "patient_id=" + patient_id +
                               ", cep_latency=" + cep_latency ;


                return event_data+ "\n";


            }
        });
```

Hope it helps 
Let me know if there is another solution to this problem.